# Pi 3a added 2nd Wifi TL-WN725N did hostAP procedure but desktop says "No Wireless Interfaces Found"

Tags: wifi

did this here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

... using wlan1 (onboard pi wifi) instead of wlan0.

I get  "No Wireless Interfaces Found" on the desktop wifi panel.

Also fails at step:

> sudo systemctl start hostapd

Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with an error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

journalctl -xe (output):

```
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit hostapd.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit hostapd.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit hostapd.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21243 and the job result is done.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
-- Subject: A start job for unit hostapd.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit hostapd.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21243.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: Line 11: invalid WPA passphrase length 4 (expected 8..63)
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: WPA-PSK enabled, but PSK or passphrase is not configured.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: 2 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 hostapd[4060]: Failed to initialize interface
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit hostapd.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit hostapd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 14:32:17 2600 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: A start job for unit hostapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit hostapd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21243 and the job result is failed.
Feb 26 14:32:18 2600 sudo[4065]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Feb 26 14:32:18 2600 sudo[4065]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

/etc/default/hostapd

```
# Defaults for hostapd initscript
#
# WARNING: The DAEMON_CONF setting has been deprecated and will be removed
#          in future package releases.
#
# See /usr/share/doc/hostapd/README.Debian for information about alternative
# methods of managing hostapd.
#
# Uncomment and set DAEMON_CONF to the absolute path of a hostapd configuration
# file and hostapd will be started during system boot. An example configuration
# file can be found at /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz
#
#DAEMON_CONF=""

# Additional daemon options to be appended to hostapd command:-
#   -d   show more debug messages (-dd for even more)
#   -K   include key data in debug messages
#   -t   include timestamps in some debug messages
#
# Note that -B (daemon mode) and -P (pidfile) options are automatically
# configured by the init.d script and must not be added to DAEMON_OPTS.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan1
#driver=nl80211
ssid=2600
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=26000062
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.77.2,192.168.77.202,255.255.255.0,24h
```

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 853  bytes 56916 (55.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 853  bytes 56916 (55.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:3e:aa:4d:8d:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

service hostapd status

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-27 14:45:16 CST; 1s ago
  Process: 4403 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Please [update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108782/edit) the question after you solve the `Line 11: invalid WPA passphrase length 4 (expected 8..63)`.

Comment: Additionally, the URL you have added doesn't work.

Comment: not sure why the link fails on this page. I can copy and past and it works.

Comment: Looks like the Wifi password was too short (problem 1) ... and I needed to comment out ... DAEMON_OPT= ... and use instead DAEMON_CONF= ... in ... /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf ... when running buster (problem 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the Raspbian version, however, I imagine it's Buster. One of the possibilities is about "Wifi Country Code". Run `raspi-conf` and go to `4 Localisation Options` then `I4 Change Wi-fi Country`. Finally, set your country. I set `IR Iran` and it has worked like a charm.

If it gives an error like `Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant` after changing Wifi country, follow [this link](https://www.qlcplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12468#p54247) to solve it.

---

You need to set everything as default. I recommend a fresh install of the OS then follow the procedure of installing raspberry pi AP. As usual, the default (built-in) wireless adapter would be `wlan0` and another new attached would be `wlan1`.
Follow [the procedure](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) step by step.

---

Remove this line of `/etc/default/hostapd`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Then restart the service:

```
service hostapd restart
```

Check the status by:

```
service hostapd status
```

Note that you configure `dnsmasq`'s interface as `wlan1` hence you must as a static IP address for `wlan1` in `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: OS is buster yes ...

Comment: Country code is set in wpa_supplicant.conf. rasp-config comes back as not set even though I set it and rebooted twice. I do see the desktop Wifi icon go active, then inactive over and over. It is doing this on wlan1 (Pi 3A internal). This is what I want hostapd to use. the USB wlan0 I want as outside NAT PAT.

Comment: In the article you link to I see the creation of a file named:  wpa_supplicant_wlan0.conf ... will that only be for that interface?

Comment: I do see that iwconfig shows ... wlan0 Mode:Auto ... and ... wlan1 Mode:Managed. I wanted wlan1 (Pi 3A internal to be hooked to hostapd not the desktop manager. How do I change this?

Comment: I deleted wpa_supplicant.conf. I then rebooted but still cannot get the country code to US in raspberry Pi Config GUI. no matter what I do comes back not set.

Comment: @keithbradley Answer just updated. Add these config files/command output to the question: `cat /etc/default/hostapd` - `cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` - `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf` - `ifconfig` - `iwconfig` - `service hostapd status`.

Comment: new info posted.

Comment: @keithbradley Answer just updated.

Comment: well that worked but I can't understand why the instructions above does not say this and why it would even care? ... one last question ... in the (fixed) link above it has ... sudo iptables -t ... blah blah ... eth0 ... since I am on Pi 3A (no eth) which wlan do I want to replace eth0?

Comment: @keithbradley The link that you have added said add `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"` to that specific file. -- Exactly that. Change all `eth0` commands to `wlan0`.

Answer (score 1):

As you was told on the log your password given in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` on line 11 with length 4 is to short, expected is 8..63. Because of this it has failed to initialize the interface.

Just give a password with min. length of 8 characters and the interface should come up.

Comment: I looked but did not see ... thanks Ingo. Still get no wifi adapter on the desktop.

Comment: Ingo - the password is now 8 and the original error is gone ... but now I get "wlan1: Could not connect to kernel driver". The link above (now fixed) says to add driver=nl80211 to /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf. I assume this is the correct driver for the on board Pi 3A Wifi ??

Comment: @keithbradley Please update your question with the new information so I can better refer to it.

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: Ingo ...you helped answer the short Wifi password issue ... but I can't seem to check yours as an answer in addition to M. Rostami ... sorry?