# Cannot manage wlan0 from desktop

Tags: wifi, raspbian-buster, iptables, hostapd

Good day all Pi folks!

I have a Pi 3A (buster) which has the onboard Wifi (wlan1) configured as an access point.
I installed a second Wifi USB TL-WN725N which comes up as wlan0 and is the outside nat'ed interface I wish to use to connect to the internet.

please see this post for current config:

[Pi 3a added 2nd Wifi TL-WN725N did hostAP procedure but desktop says "No Wireless Interfaces Found"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pi-3a-added-2nd-wifi-tl-wn725n-did-hostap-procedure-but-desktop-says-no-wireles#108795)

I cannot manage it from the desktop to connect to anything.

Command line iwlist does not work either.

Comment: Without knowing what **YOU** did you will get only speculation.

Comment: Link above has current config and a 2nd link to the procedure.

Comment: If you seriously expect people to follow 2 links and then guess which of many options you did (and if correctly)  you will get only speculation by those with time on their hands.

Comment: How did you connect to another Wifi (SSID) by the `wlan0`? I mean, did you set that by `wpa_supplicant?

Comment: Since adding wlan0 I have never been able to do anything with it. wlan1 is working as the AP. I did not do the bridge steps FYI.

Comment: You already asked the same question with the link you have given and you accepted its answer. So what is your problem now if have had a solution? What is the difference now to that solution?

Comment: My original (issue above link) was the "Job for hostapd.service failed ..." error which was due to the too short password. This was related to getting wlan1 to work with hostapd. This is now working. Now I need to understand why I can't manage wlan0 the outside interface via iptables.

Comment: One interesting thing I noticed ... I bought a 2nd Pi 3A+ and installed latest buster. I forgot to remove my 2nd wlan0 TL-N725WN usb WiFi adapter and was also unable to set the country code. when I removed the usb adapter and rebooted ... I was able to set country code and all was well ... why would the 2nd usb WiFi adapter block this?